# Recover accidentally deleted files from iCloud

Tags: ipad, icloud, data-recovery

Is there a way to recover files deleted from iCloud if an offline iPad still has them locally?

Would renaming the local files on the iPad prevent them from being deleted once the iPad is synced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to recover the files by first of all renaming them on the iPad to prevent accidentally syncing the deletion and then following the iTunes document transfer procedure as described on the [Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH23932?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US):

> 1. Open Numbers on your device, then do one of the following:
>
>    - If the spreadsheet is open: Tap the More button [image], then tap Send a Copy.
>    - If the spreadsheet is closed: Tap Share button [image] in the spreadsheet manager, tap Send a
>        Copy, then tap the spreadsheet you want to transfer.
> 2. Tap the spreadsheet format you want to export: Numbers, PDF, Excel, or CSV.
> 3. Tap iTunes.
> 4. Connect your iOS device to your computer (or use iTunes Wi-Fi Sync),
>      then open iTunes on your computer. After a moment, your iOS device
>      appears at the top of the iTunes toolbar.
> 5. In iTunes on your computer, select your iOS device, then click Apps 
>      on the left side of the window.
> 6. Scroll to the bottom of the window, then select Numbers (below File
>      Sharing). If you don’t see the File Sharing section, make sure
>      you’re not scrolling the Apps list.
> 7. Select the spreadsheet, click Save to, choose a location, then click
>      Save to.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply login to [iCloud.com](https://www.icloud.com/#settings) to recover that file. Under **iCloud Settings** (by clicking your name in the top-right corner) you will find a section named **Advanced**. Simply click `Restore Files` under **Advanced** to open the Recently Deleted File browser.

[image: iCloud Advanced Settings]